# Do slow function calls inside response.write() block the event loop?

Tags: node.js

So, after reading a little about non-blocking code, does...

```
response.write(thisWillTakeALongTime());
```

...block the process?  If so, do we need to pass the response into pretty much every slow function call we make, and have that function handle the response?

Thanks for helping to clarify!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will block the event loop.  And passing the response object into the slow function won't help, no matter where you call the slow function you will be blocking the event loop.

As to how to fix it, we will need more information.

What is making your slow function slow? Are you performing large calculations?
Are you doing sync versions of file/database calls?

Comment: Thanks david.. let's say were doing a large calculation such as working out the value of PI and returning it.  In this case, could we pass a callback to the long function and have that handle the response?  The processing still has to be done, but would that free the event loop?

Comment: @user1181545 Unfortunately not, there is only one thread, so no matter where you do the calculation you will still be blocking the event loop.  If you can't get around the calculation (by caching or pre-calculating) then you will have to start spinning off extra processess.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by process. The web server has already finished serving the page at this point you js will execute however the request is synchronous so the javascript will continue to devote its in your function until it returns regardless even if take years. (hopefully by this point the browser will detect your script is taking too long and give you the opportunity to kill it). Even still you suffer the embarrassment of the user having to kill your javascript functionality and them not being able to use the page.

So how do you solve the problem. The time when this gets particular important is when your js is making the problem because at the point a whole host of things of things can go wrong. Imagine that your user is on the other side of the earth. the network latency could make your js painfully slow. when using ajax its preferable to use Asynchronous requests which get around this. I personally recommend using jquery as it makes async ajax calls really easy and the documentation on the side is quite straight forward. The other thing I recommend is making the return output small. It made be better to return json output and build the needed html from that.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear.. this is in regard to javascript running on the server blocking the event loop